# How to correctly configure iptables on a laptop?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, docker

I have run these commands (tried switching the order too) because I want to set up a firewall on my laptop so that nobody can connect to it (except of course in response to a connection I've made):

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

But after running these I can't connect to anything over the network. `sudo iptables-save` shows:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [12:4113]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [69:5063]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [69:5063]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -d 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT DROP [9:543]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [214:41758]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Do the docker rules have anything to do with why this isn't working?

Comment: Could you post the output of `iptables -t DOCKER -L` - if I'm reading the output of `iptables-save` correctly, that should list the rule in the `DOCKER` table - which your jump rules are sending all `OUTPUT` rules to that are not destined for localhost

Comment: Running the command you mentioned @Andrew even with sudo gives `iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table 'DOCKER': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.` Any ideas what I need to change in my iptables to be compatible with docker?

Comment: @user779159 Your ruleset is incomplete until the docker daemon has been launched. Make sure it is running before looking at the iptables run-time rules. Either launch docker directly or launch a container.